# Paperclip not deleting attachments after model is destroyed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I have a Rails 4 app and when I upgrade from Paperclip 3.5.2 to any of the newer versions, my attachments are no longer deleted from the filesystem after the associated model is destroyed.  I can't see anything in the documentation that seems to have changed?

Here is my model code:

```
  has_attached_file :artwork, :styles => {:large => ["1400x1400#", :jpg],
                                          :cover => ["600x600#", :jpg],
                                          :medium => "170x170#",
                                          :thumb =>  "50x50#"},
                              :convert_options => {:all => "-quality 80 -colorspace RGB"}
```

Anything look incorrect?